# Login with python requests and csrf-token

Tags: python, python-requests, csrf

I am using the requests module for python to try to login on a webpage. I open up a requests.session(), then I get the cookie and the csrf-token which is included in a meta tag. I build up my payload with username, password, a hidden input field and the csrf-token from the meta tag. After that i use the post method and I am passing through the login url, the cookie, the payload and the header. But after that I can't access a page behind the login page.
What am I doing wrong?

This is the request header when I perfom a login:

```
Request Headers:

:authority: www.die-staemme.de
:method: POST
:path: /page/auth
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
content-length: 50
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: cid=261197879; remember_optout=0; ref=start; 
PHPSESSID=3eb4f503f38bfda1c6f48b8f9036574a
origin: https://www.die-staemme.de
referer: https://www.die-staemme.de/
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
x-csrf-token: 3c49b84153f91578285e0dc4f22491126c3dfecdabfbf144
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

This is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import lxml

# Page header
head= { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'
}
# Start Page
url = 'https://www.die-staemme.de/'
# Login URL
login_url = 'https://www.die-staemme.de/page/auth'
# URL behind the login page
url2= 'https://de159.die-staemme.de/game.php?screen=overview&intro'

# Open up a session
s = requests.session()

# Open the login page
r = s.get(url)

# Get the csrf-token from meta tag
soup = bs(r.text,'lxml')
csrf_token = soup.select_one('meta[name="csrf-token"]')['content']

# Get the page cookie
cookie = r.cookies

# Set CSRF-Token
head['X-CSRF-Token'] = csrf_token
head['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'

# Build the login payload
payload = {
'username': '', #<-- your username
'password': '', #<-- your password
'remember':'1' 
}

# Try to login to the page
r = s.post(login_url, cookies=cookie, data=payload, headers=head)

# Try to get a page behind the login page
r = s.get(url2)

# Check if login was successful, if so there have to be an element with the id menu_row2
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
element = soup.select('#menu_row2')
print(element)
```

Comment: You didn'r request from the `form action= url`

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use `url = 'https://www.die-staemme.de/'` or `url = 'https://www.die-staemme.de/#'`

Comment: I also tried `url='https://www.die-staemme.de/page/auth'`

Comment: This site doesn't use `x-www-form-urlencoded`, so `.post(..., data=payload` will not work. Use a browser tool to show the header used at login and adapt accordingly.

Comment: If I use the browser tool I get a request header in which I see `accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01` so I need json insead of data? But if I use json it does't work either

Comment: change to `'X-CSRF-Token' : csrf_token` (token should set in header) and login url is `https://www.die-staemme.de/page/auth`

Comment: *"`accept: ...`"*: That's the wrong header, you need `Content-Type:`.

Comment: I added `head['x-csrf-token'] = csrf_token` instead to payload. I now use `https://www.die-staemme.de/page/auth` as login url. But I don't get it with the `content-type` and `accept: ...`. When I use the browser tool I get `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but I also tried `content-type: application/json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth noting that your request, when using the Python Requests module, will not be the exact same as a standard user request. In order to fully mimic a realistic request, and thus not be blocked by any firewall or security measures by the site, you will need to copy both all POST parameters, GET parameters and finally headers.

You can use a tool such as [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp) to intercept the login request. Copy the URL it is sending it to, copy all POST parameters also, and finally copy all headers. You should be using the `requests.Session()` function in order to store cookies. You may also want to do a initial session GET request to the homepage in order to pick up cookies as it is not realistic for a user to send a login request without first visiting the homepage.

I hope that makes sense, header parameters can be passed like so:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'My User Agent (copy your real one for a realistic request).'
}

data = {
    'username': 'John',
    'password': 'Doe'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.get("https://mywebsite.com/")
s.post("https://mywebsite.com/", data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I finally made it :) I built a header before I did the first get request, then I built a new header for the post request. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. I have had similar issues in the past due to headers being flagged as spam.

Comment: I'm stuck on the same thing currently. when you say "built a header" you mean you had to pull out all the header keys (`authority`, `user-agent`, `cookie`, etc) and use those `headers` on every request?

Comment: By default, `requests` sends a pyrequests user agent which is often blocked by a lot of web application firewalls due to it being an obvious attempt at automated scanning. Changing this to a realistic user agent will often work. If you're receiving authorization errors, then you may also need to include authentication headers, or perhaps authenticated cookies, with your request.

Answer (score 0):

had also the same issue. what did it for me was to add

```
    s.headers.update(headers)
```

before the first get request in Cillian Collins example.